# Sharing data across ViewControllers

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

After reading a bunch of stackoverflow posts and forums I got really confused on this subject. Alot speak about using delegates, but can result in memory problem if there is a big amount of data.

I am only to handle around 600-bytes of data from a TCP/IP device and override the existing value with the new.

I have made a `RootViewController` which has a special view and the TCP/IP socket, furthermore I have two other ViewControllers which has to use data from the `RootViewController` (TCP/IP).

Should I perhaps make a seperate class for the TCP stuff instead of mixing it up in my RootViewController?

Also how should I handle the sharing of data across the ViewControllers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sharing data among classes you can use notifications mechanism. Post a notification in your **FromClass.m**:

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:yourTCPData, @"TCPData", nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"gotTCPData" object:nil userInfo:options];
```

In your **ToClass.m** viewDidLoad add this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(makeSomeThingUsefulWithTCPData:)name:@"gotTCPData" object:nil];
```

...and somewhere in your **ToClass.m** add this method:

```
- (void)makeSomeThingUsefulWithTCPData:(NSNotification *)notification {
  NSDictionary *dict = [notification userInfo];
  yourTCPDataClass *yourTCPDataObject = [dict objectForKey:@"TCPData"];
  // Here make something useful with your TCP data
  }
```

Also add this in your **ToClass.m** viewDidUnload to release observer object when view will be unloaded:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Comment: Where is the data involved? I will try and implement this.

Comment: You data is in yourTCPData object. Post notification from first code snippet in any place you need to send the data to another object.

Comment: So the `object:nil` should be set to a real object?

Comment: userInfo:options should be set to a real object.

Comment: Could you kindly give a complete example with object data?

Comment: Then name your array as **yourTCPData**.

Comment: `Implicit conversion of a non-Objective-C pointer type 'double *' to 'id' is disallowed with ARC` should i encapsulate my double array?

Comment: yep, youTCPData must be an object.

Comment: How would i be able to put a double array[] in a object?

Comment: convert all doubles to NSNumber and make NSArray of NSNumbers.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing a lot with your TCP 'stuff' (for example get the data, display the data, reformat the data, compair or change the data and then re-save etc) then I would suggest creating a separate class (probably NSObject) that has all the metods to handle the TCP stuff and then create an instance of that object in your root view controller.

As for getting the data in other view controllers you would have to create a reference to your root view controller in other view controllers and then connect them in interface builder (or programmatically). Just make sure you dont create a brand new instance of root view controller (i.e. dont use [[RootViewController alloc] init];)

Does that make sense? If you post more about the structure of your app (like are you using a navigation controller etc) I could be more specific for you.

Good luck!

Comment: If it makes any difference i use tabbar. I have implemented the class for my TCP controller and it works quite fine with a singleton.